# Write a method to print an array with a number loop

Tags: arrays, string

If an array called myStrings shows (there is four terms however one is blank)

E
 J 
 M 
 T

in the array write the method that would print this array when invoked. The following is acceptable output: 
 0. E
 1. J
 2. M
 3. T
 4.

Comment: in which programming language???

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code written in `Java`:

```
   public class Exercise4 {

    // printPattern Method
    public static void printPattern(String[] myStrings) {
        // Printing myStrings values
        for(int i=0; i<myStrings.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ". " + myStrings[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] myStrings = {"E", "J", "M", "T", " "}; // myStrings array

        printPattern(myStrings);
    }
}
```